# Polymer paper-checkbox properties

Tags: polymer

I am trying to create a register page using pure polymer. I used a paper-checkbox to let user check and agree the term of use. And my intention was only to display the submit button, (paper-button ) if the user has checked the user agreement. I am just wondering if there is a way that I can accomplish this using pure polymer instead of java script. I know paper-checkbox has a boolean property called "checked". I figure it would be nice that I could access this property inside my submit button and disable the button if checked is false.

Here is what I have, but it does not work

```
<paper-checkbox id="checkbox" checked$="{{ checked }}"> I agree user terms
</paper-checkbox>
<paper-button raised disabled$="{{ checked }}" onclick="submitForm()">Create  
ID</paper-button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in a `dom-bind`, and invert your disabled binding.  Additionally, you want to bind to the element `property` rather than the `attribute`, so you can lose the dollar signs:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <paper-checkbox id="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}"> I agree to user terms</paper-checkbox>
  <paper-button raised disabled="[[!checked]]" on-click="submitForm">Create ID</paper-button>
</template>
```